# Prevent user has the same count from table

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am doing a lucky draw method whereas users can only get the lucky draw when the number of tries hit the certain numbers.

In order to do this, I have a table called gifts, it will save each time the user try to lucky draw. I have created a simple method to do this.

```
public function canGetLuckyDraw()
{
    $gifts = Gift::count();

    Gift::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id,
        'status' => false
    ]);

    if($gifts % 300 == 0)
    {
        $this->userGetTheLuckyDraw();
    }
}
```

When the current user is at 300 tries. Then the user will get the lucky draw. The problem is that I found that if both users are accessing the canGetLuckyDraw() method at the same time. There is a chance that the count from gifts table will be the same and two or more users will get the lucky draw.

Anyone knows what is the best way of handling situation like this? I have used queue, but it kinda slow as I am forced to use only 1 worker to handle this to ensure the count is unique.

Comment: What is the functionality is `Gift::count()`??

Comment: I think there is small chance it to happen. . After executing the code (that happens in i bet 1 second or less) next execute cant get same

Comment: you just have to make sure you only award the gift to one person

Comment: @Ingus if there is a chance mean if 10k users will make the chances higher.

Comment: @Kevin sound good. but could u pls explain further?

Comment: shouldn't you just get the 300th entry for that particular gift if that's the case, if its saved in a table it should be straightforward

Comment: @Kevin if both accessing the method at the same time. I will not know which user is the real 300th.

Comment: do you have a table that holds all submissions (draws)?(with gift id and user id) if the primary ids are autoincremented you wouldn't have to worry about that. that's what auto increment is supposed to be or its job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216291/discussion-between-dave-cruise-and-kevin).

Answer (score 1):

Use where clause and count.
 `$gifts = Gift::where('user_id', auth()->id)->count();`

Comment: It has to be the total of tries by all users.

Comment: then you have to create first before counting

Comment: uhm, then you have to get the id then perform modulo. let's say id is autoincremented then you'll just have to base your count to the latest id the return of create function

Comment: $gifts = Gift::create(['user_id' => auth()->id, 'status' => false]);  if($gifts % 300 == 0){$this->userGetTheLuckyDraw()};

Comment: Let me have a try on this first. Thanks btw, if it works i will mark this as answer

Comment: Sorry it must be `$gifts = Gift::create(['user_id' => auth()->id, 'status' => false])->id`

Comment: Thanks for your idea Bevin. I get what the expected result based on your idea. It works very well.

Comment: For people who faced this issue and wanted to get the count that include other users, you can use Gift::where('id', '<=', $gift->id)->count(); after the gift created.